# Chrome Ash full screen

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, fullscreen, kiosk

With "google-chrome --open-ash" chrome starts in ash mode, but how to create launcher to start in fullscreen (not kiosk mode but the same as F11)?

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Asus 1000HE Eee PC (32-bit, 2GB RAM, 128GB SSD). Fedora 21 with Gnome Shell runs ok, but as I only use this netbook to browse the web, I figured I’d try to figure out how to launch Chrome as the desktop environment, cutting Gnome Shell out completely.  In the process of trying to determine which lightweight window manager I would use, I discovered that Google Chrome (my browser of choice) includes it’s own called Ash. So, setting this up was as easy as creating a single file, and simply selecting “Chrome” as my login session from GDM.

`/etc/X11/sessions/chrome.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chrome
Comment=Chrome Browser
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome --open-ash --ash-force-desktop --ash-host-window-bounds="1024x600"
TryExec=/usr/bin/google-chrome
Icon=
Type=Application
DesktopNames=Chrome
```

This isn’t a perfect solution, but it’s pretty neat. A few problems:

Triggering a download crashes the browser, as Chrome can’t launch the Gnome (GTK?) download widget.
No battery, audio, or wifi system icons.

Initially, the desktop was off-center.  Apparently, the netbook screen size (1024×600) was odd, so it needed to be explicitly specified with the “-bounds” parameter.

---

Copied verbatim from the web ...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! When using what others wrote (or maybe even if you had it posted elsewhere first), you must reference your source. Otherwise, your answer might end up deleted. Please see [How to reference material written by others](http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing)

Comment: This is probably the source: https://forsetti.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/chrome-as-your-desktop-environment/